# How do I sweep a Polkadot wallet?

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, polkadot-js, polkadot

I want move all funds from one wallet to another, without leaving any DOT dust behind. How do I do a "send all" with the [Polkadot JS UI](https://polkadot.js.org/apps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no such functionality in the UI, or in the RPC used to directly interact with a Kusama or Polkadot node. However, since transfers cost 0.001, you're safe if you transfer `MAX - 0.001` - this should result in you completely emptying the original account. Here are the records of an account on which I tested this: https://polkascan.io/pre/kusama-cc3/account/CgiiSCGqEc9bgSoFYT5WcUEsvWDG1XDZLKDgjabGAbb5sBK

So, if you have 10 KSM to send, send 9.999 and you'll end up with 0 in the original address.

You can check how much a transfer costs by using [Polkadot JS UI](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/chainstate/constants) and going to Constants, then `balances`, and then `transferFee`:

[image]

Comment: Note that this is only valid as long as there are no weight/fees involved aside from the mentioned `TransferFee`. See here: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/development/module/fees#fee-calculation